# Why I can't comment on other's questions?

Tags: support, status-completed, comments, user-accounts

I can't comment on others questions or answers. Is there any privilege to comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To comment on other people's posts (not just your own questions or answers), you need a minimum of 50 reputation.

All the other privileges, and minimum required reputation for each is described in the [Help Centre](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)